# How to use python to get information from the map navigation container of a website?

Tags: python, web-scraping, heremap-navigation

I am learning Python and hope to get some information from a map navigation container of this website https://findmasa.com/view/map#b1cc410b, such as mural id, latitude, longitude, artist name, address, city, and state.

Below is the code I tried before, but the output is always NO DATA. My coding skill is limited so any help would be sincerely appreciated!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://findmasa.com/view/map#b1cc410b'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

li_element = soup.find('li', id='b1cc410b')

if li_element:
    data_lat = li_element['data-lat']
    data_lng = li_element['data-lng']
    artist_name = li_element.find('a').text
    address = li_element.find_all('p')[1].text
    city = li_element.find_all('p')[2].text

    print('LATITUDE ', data_lat)
    print('LONGITUDE ', data_lng)
    print('ARTIST ', artist_name)
    print('ADDRESS ', address)
    print('CITY ', city)
else:
    print('NO DATA')
```

Comment: Consider selenium: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/selenium-python-tutorial/

Comment: StackOverflow is a site for debugging any errors or issues, so it'd be better if you put the problematic code, current output, and expected output, so we can help. Without any details, the question will get closed soon.

Comment: Web sites today are often dynamic. The initial page code does not contain the map info. Instead, it contains code to load that info and update the page.

Comment: @Ouroborus Should I consider this website as a dynamic website? My understanding of a dynamic website is that the information changes automatically whenever you open it. How should I get the information hidden behind?

Comment: Yes. You either use a browser as a proxy (Selenium, etc.) or you find and access its API directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information you're looking for gets loaded slowly and involves Javascript. As the `requests` library doesn't support the javascript, it doesn't return the content/information and thus your `if-statement` gets `False`. So, it goes to the `else-statement` and you get `NO DATA`.

You may try using `Selenium`

Here's the solution

```py
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC

# Create a Chrome driver instance
driver = Chrome()

url = 'https://findmasa.com/view/map#b1cc410b'
driver.get(url)

# Wait for the li element with id 'b1cc410b' to be present on the page
li_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'li#b1cc410b')))

data_lat = li_element.get_attribute('data-lat')
data_lng = li_element.get_attribute('data-lng')
artist_name = li_element.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'a').text
address = li_element.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'p')[1].text
city = li_element.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'p')[2].text

# Print the extracted data
print(data_lat)
print(data_lng)
print(artist_name)
print(address)
print(city)
```

output:

```
34.102025
-118.32694167
Tristan Eaton
6301 Hollywood Boulevard
Los Angeles, California
```

You can install selenium using pip:

```
pip install selenium
```

[UPDATE]:

- If the id number is known beforehand, you can easily put it in a variable in order to make the code dynamic using the `f-string`
- And to overcome the `InvalidSelectorException` that you're getting for some url or better to say for some id number, use the notation `li[id="id_value"]` instead of `li#id_value`.

  ```py
  from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
  import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC

  # Create a Chrome driver instance
  driver = Chrome()
  variable_name = '1456a64a' # fdd8a7d5, b1cc410b
  url = f'https://findmasa.com/view/map#{variable_name}'
  driver.get(url)

  # Wait for the li element with id 'b1cc410b' to be present on the page
  li_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, f'li[id="{variable_name}"]')))

  data_lat = li_element.get_attribute('data-lat')
  data_lng = li_element.get_attribute('data-lng')
  artist_name = li_element.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'a').text
  address = li_element.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'p')[1].text
  city = li_element.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'p')[2].text

  # Print the extracted data
  print(data_lat)
  print(data_lng)
  print(artist_name)
  print(address)
  print(city)
  ```

  output:

  ```
  34.0536722
  -118.3041877
  unknown
  960 South Harvard Boulevard
  Los Angeles, California
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much for your clarification. The first time I run this updated code, I had the same output as yours. But the second time I got an error message <selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: >. Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: the only source of this TimeoutException is this line `li_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'li#b1cc410b')))
`, perhaps you could try increasing the wait time `li_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'li#b1cc410b')))
`  and see if that works

Comment: I changed the wait time from 10 to 30 and it worked again... Am I doing it correctly? Because I have 100+ this kind of links and I need to get the same information from each of them.

Comment: yes, I think it will work, you could make the wait time 50 also which will cover the cases where the desired element might take more time to load/appear, although 30 is enough.  It also depends on the internet speed.

Comment: Thank you! For this line `li_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'li#fdd8a7d5')))`, how should I replace the `fdd8a7d5` to a variable that I created representing the same id number?

Comment: if you want to make it dynamic using a variable(let's say `variable_name`) that holds the id number, you can simply use `f-string`.  `li_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, f'li#{variable_name}')))`

Comment: I received another error message <selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified> when I run this code to extract information from the link: findmasa.com/view/map#1456a64a Do you know what the problem is and how to fix it? Thank you again for all your kind help!!

Comment: Please check the solution in the updated answer above